# Fvwm Style For the windows

Tags: styles, window

I currently use `FPClickToFocus, FPClickDecorToFocus, FPClickIconToFocus,  FPGrabFocusTransient` for the window style. But the Problem is the Window loses Focus when mouse leave it and give the focus to the window it is in;
So which Style(s) give the normal fill and look in this specific matter; like other WMs openbox, gnome ... (i.e click in the window or on its titlebar; gives it focus and bring it on top)

Answer (score 0):

Using this below Style(look down) only changes and brings window to the front but the Focus (the window that action happens in i.e i can type in) doesn't change.
It means I change a window but my cursor is still in my geany and  i am typing a web-site URL in geany while the firefox is in front and nothing happening in its addressbar For Example.

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# The focus policy. Once you are used to clicking *inside* windows to
# raise them you will not want to lose this feature.
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Style * ClickToFocus
Style * MouseFocusClickRaises
```